# Edit a .liquid file from shopify in eclipse with correct code styling

Tags: eclipse, liquid, shopify

I am building a store using shopify.

I'd like to edit the template files offline in eclipse, but they are [.liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid) files, which eclipse doesn't recognize.

How do I make a custom content type for the liquid template files that eclipse will recognize?

---

There are two types of markup in liquid: Output and Tag.

**Output** is surrounded by:

```
{{ two curly brackets }}
```

**Tags** are surrounded by:

```
{% a curly bracket and a percent %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question might already have your answer:

[Eclipse plug-in: Create a new file extension for a language not supported by Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838558/eclipse-plug-in-create-a-new-file-extension-for-a-language-not-supported-by-ecl)

If you aren't opposed to using a different editor, there is a Liquid mode for TextMate, which I think may also work on Sublime Text (if you aren't using a mac).  Then of course there's surely got to be an emacs or vim plugin.