# Eclipse CDT: how to add support for new filetype

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT, I would like to create syntax highlighting and a error parser for a custom filetype, lets say *.xy.
Those files do not contain C-Code, so i cannot use any existing parsers.

What kind of plugins would I have to create?

For the error parser, I think I have to use Codan? (have not tried it yet)
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codan/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse plug-in: Create a new file extension for a language not supported by Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838558/eclipse-plug-in-create-a-new-file-extension-for-a-language-not-supported-by-ecl)

Answer (score 1):

The CDT is the wrong start for your journey, if your language is not related to the CDT supported languages and workflows. Implement an [xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) based language editor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a simple solution for you:
[colorEditor plugin](http://gstaff.org/colorEditor/)

You can simply add a new language by unpacking the jar archive, then adding a xyz.xml file for your .xyz files.
Pakc together again, and copy into your Eclipse "plugins" dir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a new "language" - this is the extension point: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_core_language.html

Codan is not an "error parser" it is a static analysis framework. Error parser processes output of the command-line tools you use to build the application (e.g. compiler, linker) to identify errors that happened during the build and filling their attributes, e.g. source file name and line number.

Codan analyzes the source code in the editor to identify errors. E.g. it checks if the variable used in the expression was declared beforehand. Note that same check can be performed by a compile at a build time and then captured by error parser and shown in the editor/problems view - the goal of Codan is to detect problems sooner, before the build is even ran. Codan can also perform some checks that compiler doesn't.

Comment: The language extension point states "Practically this is limited to C/C++ language variants only. Completely different languages cannot be modelled reasonably using this extension point."
My new file type is pretty much completely different from c.
The solution was to create a completely new editor, which provides syntax highlighting etc.
I was looking too much around the CDT framework instead of just eclipse itself.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure how up-to-date that description is. Make sure to check Fortran support from PTP - to me it sounds like a language quite different from C.